# How to create a calculation on the dashboard between two different worksheets in Tableau?

Tags: parameters, tableau-api, dashboard, worksheet, calculated-field

I'd like to create a calculation on a dashboard that has inputs from two different worksheets.

In other words, I have one bar in a  worksheet called 'Closed Won Deals' and another bar in another worksheet called 'Intro'd Deals.' I've placed both on the same dashboard, but I'd like to divide the number of closed won deals by the number of Intro'd deals on the dashboard.

[image]

In this case, I'd like to divide 29/254 to attain 11.4%.

I've tried to accomplish this by doing the following: 
1) Create a calculated field for Closed Won Deals that would sum to 29
2) Create a calculated field for Intro'd Deals that would sum to 254
3) Create a calculated field for 'Conversion Rate' by dividing the calculate dfield for Closed Won Deals by the calculated field for Intro'd deals, which looks like the following:

```
sum([Intod deals])/SUM([Closed Won Deals])
```

However, I get the incorrect conversion. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What result are you getting ? Try formatting the output to decimal by right clicking the calculated field .

Comment: Calculations are scoped to data sources -- not worksheets. Each worksheet references a single (primary) data source -- indicated with a blue check mark -- and optionally any number of secondary data sources, marked in orange when shown. You can think of a data source as a database query with related metadata.

Comment: Is your data in one data source or multiple? Post the table structure, and people can help. Otherwise we can only guess what your data looks like. Usually, there are easy ways to make ratios that involve little or no hard coded calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(now this is just an idea.)

```
sum([Intod deals])/SUM([Closed Won Deals])
```

=> would be translated to: (sum = [Intod deals])) / [Cloded Won Deals]
try to add one more bracket to make it:

```
sum(([Intod deals])/SUM([Closed Won Deals]))
```